# System.Webserver rewrite and secure at the same time

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, membership-provider

I'm serving Confluence through IIS to end user, here is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="True" />
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="\+" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{UrlDecode:{REQUEST_URI}}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="inbound" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8090/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
            <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
            <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <remove name="CGI-exe" />
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Confluence runs in it's own process on port 8090
What I want is somehow add confluence as a subfolder to another site so it goes to:

site.com/confluence

site.com is ASP.NET website. I'd like to password-protect /confluence folder.

So, if user logged in to site.com (ASP.NET Membership provider) - they get access to /confluence folder.

Is this possible and how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is Delegated Authentication of a IIS Reverse Proxy.

This is technically possible.

You don't want to do this. Because you would need to use ASP.Net authentication to view the website. But then you also need to log in using your confluence log in.

You actually want to use

- IIS Reverse Proxy/Application Request Routing (this puts the Confluence website in the "subfolder")
- Single Sign-on Integration with ASP.Net Membership.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/single-sign-on-integration-with-the-atlassian-stack-794495126.html

With this solution, Confluence uses Crowd to connect to ASP.Net using OpenID.

I recommend using [IdentityServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3/) to expose your ASP.Net Membership Provider to the OpenID api.

Comment: We are OK that we have to login twice. Because only US will be editing wiki, 2 people. Other users just need RO access.

Comment: @katit It is impossible to use Delegated Authentication with a ASP.Net Membership provider on ARR. ARR is an IIS component that works at the HTTP layer. ASP.Net Membership runs at the Application layer, which is happening on your Confluence server. It would be possible to implement Windows AD Authentication with ARR.

Comment: Any other way where we can control access to it via .NET code? Write our own router, etc?

Comment: @katit Go with the OpenID solution. It works, its tested, its off the shelf. You'd be writing a HTTP reverse proxy in .net to get this to work.

Comment: With Open ID we would have to pay for user licenses and this is cost-prohibitive. Right now our help system is open to WWW so anyone can read it. We just want to limit it to our customers. Also editing only done by 2 users.